# On finding the Least Upper bound of a set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x>0, \; \; x^2 < 2 \} $. I want to show that $\sup A = \sqrt{2} $. My attempt:

Since $1 \in A$, $A \neq \varnothing$. Let $x \in A $. Then, we have $x^2 < 2 \implies -\sqrt{2} < x < \sqrt{2} $. Since this is true for any $x \in A$, then we have that $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound of $A$. So, $\sup A = y$ exists. I want to show that $y = \sqrt{2}$ or that $y^2 = 2 $. How Can I proceed from here?

Comment: What is sqrt(2)? I mean, how do you know that there exists a real number whose square is 2? In fact, one way to define sqrt(2) is through this supremum, which exists for any bounded non-empty subset of the reals, by the completeness axiom. Now, try to show that the square of this supremum is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is for $x=\sup A$ to assume $x^2<2$ so that we must have $x^2+\varepsilon=2$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. But then one can show that for $\delta>0$ small enough it is possible to prove that
$$
(x+\delta)^2<x^2+\varepsilon=2
$$
contradicting that $x$ is the supremum of $A$, since we have found a number larger than $x$ still in $A$.

---

It is not reasonable to compare numbers to $\sqrt 2$ in any part of your proof since we do not know whether $\sqrt 2$ even exists. You can only compare squared number to $2$, which is the way to go about it.

Comment: BTW one should also work on rejecting the possibility of $x^2>2$. But that is written over the same tune ...

Answer (score 0):

It's important to precise if $A$ is consider as a subset of $\mathbb R$ or of $\mathbb Q$. But we'll consider $A$ like a subset of $\mathbb R$ (otherwise $\sup A$ doesn't exist). An other way would be to remark that $A=]0,\sqrt 2[\cap\mathbb Q$. Then, by density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset ]0,\sqrt 2[$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=\sqrt 2$ what conclude the proof.